# How to merge Firefox bookmarks exported as json (dictionaries within dictionaries structure)

Tags: python, recursion, parent-child

I am trying to make a new dictionary that is made from an existing dictionary that it has been creating from a function which tries to merge two dictionaries that derive from json files from backup firefox bookmarks.

1st json bookmark dictionary:

```
json1={'guid': 'root________', 'title': '', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1697130233008000, 'id': 1, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'placesRoot', 'children': [{'guid': 'menu________', 'title': 'menu', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1697130233008000, 'id': 2, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'bookmarksMenuFolder', 'children': [{'guid': '9GEAbdFPVBqv', 'title': 'Getting started - mypy 1.5.1 documentation', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1696274666207000, 'lastModified': 1696274666207000, 'id': 16, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html'}, {'guid': 'PDKXoMPpSKZ9', 'title': 'testFolder2', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130042452000, 'lastModified': 1697130183178000, 'id': 18, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'jbP4ff424REs', 'title': 'Secure Coding with Python', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130058445000, 'lastModified': 1697130058445000, 'id': 19, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://devopedia.org/secure-coding-with-python'}, {'guid': 'bZSAKQe67MEP', 'title': 'testSubFolder', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130074677000, 'lastModified': 1697130183178000, 'id': 20, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': '0U5O4Rw6M3M5', 'title': 'Typer', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130183178000, 'lastModified': 1697130183178000, 'id': 21, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://typer.tiangolo.com/'}]}]}, {'guid': '-j27AP1Cwt0O', 'title': 'testFolder1', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1697130021758000, 'lastModified': 1697130233008000, 'id': 17, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'Wb3-R2DDT8Ip', 'title': 'Welcome to Click — Click Documentation (8.1.x)', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130230240000, 'lastModified': 1697130230240000, 'id': 22, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/'}]}, {'guid': 'VDTmkniLNlvN', 'title': 'Mozilla Firefox', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1697129949344000, 'id': 7, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'vUwrKuzYfywC', 'title': 'Get Help', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 8, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox'}, {'guid': 'mKpEl6U5Pppr', 'title': 'Customize Firefox', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 9, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize'}, {'guid': 'Rw167-bbT1fR', 'title': 'Get Involved', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 10, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/contribute/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/contribute/'}, {'guid': 'stHPEtkREVvD', 'title': 'About Us', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 11, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/about/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/about/'}]}]}, {'guid': 'toolbar_____', 'title': 'toolbar', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1696274298931000, 'id': 3, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'toolbarFolder', 'children': [{'guid': '690YbVlf5eS_', 'title': 'Getting Started', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927107484000, 'lastModified': 1688927107484000, 'id': 12, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/'}, {'guid': 'YJ_gjoZ6Wwj1', 'title': 'json — JSON encoder and decoder — Python 3.11.5 documentation', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1696274298931000, 'lastModified': 1696274298931000, 'id': 13, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html'}]}, {'guid': 'unfiled_____', 'title': 'unfiled', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1688927107332000, 'id': 5, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'unfiledBookmarksFolder'}, {'guid': 'mobile______', 'title': 'mobile', 'index': 4, 'dateAdded': 1688927106942000, 'lastModified': 1688927107332000, 'id': 6, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'mobileFolder'}]}
```

2nd json bookmark dictionary:

```
json2={'guid': 'root________', 'title': '', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 1, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'placesRoot', 'children': [{'guid': 'menu________', 'title': 'menu', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 2, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'bookmarksMenuFolder', 'children': [{'guid': '9GEAbdFPVBqv', 'title': 'Getting started - mypy 1.5.1 documentation', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1696274666207000, 'lastModified': 1696274666207000, 'id': 16, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html'}, {'guid': 'FNxknWay_xr8', 'title': "Command-line Applications — The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python", 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130502023000, 'lastModified': 1697130502023000, 'id': 23, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/cli/'}, {'guid': 'PDKXoMPpSKZ9', 'title': 'testFolder2', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1697130042452000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 18, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'bZSAKQe67MEP', 'title': 'testSubFolder', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130074677000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 20, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'm6MBObvLXgt6', 'title': 'The Python Fire Guide - Python Fire', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130663668000, 'lastModified': 1697130663668000, 'id': 28, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://google.github.io/python-fire/guide/'}, {'guid': 'fl2vHRLT-RJY', 'title': 'Typer', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697131416648000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 30, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://typer.tiangolo.com/'}]}, {'guid': 'Z2khP-DX2nJU', 'title': 'testsubF2', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130537074000, 'lastModified': 1697130642695000, 'id': 26, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'ZHUGVs2ZYUiA', 'title': 'argparse — Parser for command-line options, arguments and sub-commands — Python 3.12.0 documentation', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130642695000, 'lastModified': 1697130642695000, 'id': 27, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html'}]}, {'guid': '3RP_KOI4Pq0q', 'title': 'plac · PyPI', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1697130513781000, 'lastModified': 1697130513781000, 'id': 24, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://pypi.org/project/plac/'}]}, {'guid': '-j27AP1Cwt0O', 'title': 'testFolder1', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1697130021758000, 'lastModified': 1697130520562000, 'id': 17, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'Wb3-R2DDT8Ip', 'title': 'Welcome to Click — Click Documentation (8.1.x)', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130230240000, 'lastModified': 1697130230240000, 'id': 22, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/'}, {'guid': 'zuT4_jp_Rj5l', 'title': 'cliff – Command Line Interface Formulation Framework — cliff 4.3.1.dev12 documentation', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130520562000, 'lastModified': 1697130520562000, 'id': 25, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.openstack.org/cliff/latest/'}]}, {'guid': 'LjrKYDavnU7w', 'title': 'Generating Command-Line Interfaces (CLI) with Fire in Python', 'index': 4, 'dateAdded': 1697130696550000, 'lastModified': 1697130696550000, 'id': 29, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://stackabuse.com/generating-command-line-interfaces-cli-with-fire-in-python/'}, {'guid': 'VDTmkniLNlvN', 'title': 'Mozilla Firefox', 'index': 5, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1697129949344000, 'id': 7, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'vUwrKuzYfywC', 'title': 'Get Help', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 8, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox'}, {'guid': 'mKpEl6U5Pppr', 'title': 'Customize Firefox', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 9, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize'}, {'guid': 'Rw167-bbT1fR', 'title': 'Get Involved', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 10, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/contribute/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/contribute/'}, {'guid': 'stHPEtkREVvD', 'title': 'About Us', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 11, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/about/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/about/'}]}]}, {'guid': 'toolbar_____', 'title': 'toolbar', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1696274298931000, 'id': 3, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'toolbarFolder', 'children': [{'guid': '690YbVlf5eS_', 'title': 'Getting Started', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927107484000, 'lastModified': 1688927107484000, 'id': 12, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/'}, {'guid': 'YJ_gjoZ6Wwj1', 'title': 'json — JSON encoder and decoder — Python 3.11.5 documentation', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1696274298931000, 'lastModified': 1696274298931000, 'id': 13, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html'}]}, {'guid': 'unfiled_____', 'title': 'unfiled', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1688927107332000, 'id': 5, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'unfiledBookmarksFolder'}, {'guid': 'mobile______', 'title': 'mobile', 'index': 4, 'dateAdded': 1688927106942000, 'lastModified': 1688927107332000, 'id': 6, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'mobileFolder'}]}
```

My idea was to simplify the merging of these two dictionaries by doing:

```
def has_url(diction):
    if "uri" in diction:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def merge_dicts(dictmain, dict2):
    return {**dict2, **dictmain}



def get_bm_path(bookmarks):
    urls = {}

    def bm_path(x, name=""):
        if type(x) is dict:
            name = name + x.get("guid") + "/"
            if has_url(x):
                urls[name] = [f"uri_{x.get('guid')}", dict((k, x[k]) for k in x.keys() if k not in "children")]

            else:
                urls[name] = [f"folder_{x.get('guid')}", dict((k, x[k]) for k in x.keys() if k not in "children")]
            bm_path(x=x.get("children"), name=name)
        elif type(x) is list:
            for i, a in enumerate(x):
                bm_path(a, name=name)

    bm_path(bookmarks)
    return urls
```

Then by running:

```
merged_dict = merge_dicts(get_bm_path(json1), get_bm_path(json2))
```

I get a merged dictionary with keys that resemble folders/files structure so as not to lose the track of the parent/child structure of bookmarks while merging.

And then I need to make the function to derive from that merged dictionary the actual json structure that firefox uses.

> The minimal (maybe) reproducible example:

main dictionary:

```py
{'main_folder/': {'id': 'main_folder', 'ad': 'what'}, 'main_folder/subfolder1/': {'id': 'subfolder1', 'ad': 'what'}, 'main_folder/subfolder1/9GEAbdFPVBqv/': {'id': '9GEAbdFPVBqv', 'ad': 'what1'}, 
'main_folder/subfolder1/eaXY8H5Y1cJ_/': {'id': 'eaXY8H5Y1cJ_', 'ad': 'what2'},
'main_folder/subfolder1/eaXY8H5Y1cJ_/9p2UFp7-qcEt/': {'id': '9p2UFp7-qcEt', 'ad': 'what3'},
'main_folder/subfolder1/fijaCypbmbU1/': {'id': 'fijaCypbmbU1', 'ad': 'what4'}, 
'main_folder/subfolder2/': {'id': 'subfolder2', 'ad': 'what7'}}
```

The resulting dictionary should be something like that:

```py
{'id': 'main_folder', 'ad': 'what', 
    'children':[
     {'id': 'subfolder1', 'ad': 'what', 
        'children':[
         {'id': '9GEAbdFPVBqv', 'ad': 'what1'},
         {'id': 'eaXY8H5Y1cJ_', 'ad': 'what2',
             'children': [{'id': '9p2UFp7-qcEt', 'ad': 'what3'}]},
         {'id': 'fijaCypbmbU1', 'ad': 'what4'}
         ]
      },
      {'id': 'subfolder2', 'ad': 'what7'}
      ]
}
```

The resulting dictionary makes the tree like structure for each element (sub-folder) in a parent/child dictionary/list.
I can't find a way to reduce each "layer" of files to subfolders recursively.

Comment: Are you sure you don't rather want to end up with a structure the uses the id as a key? i.e. `{"main_folder: {"ad": "what", "children": [{"subfolder": {...}}]}` this would be a lot easier to navigate down the tree later. You could also consider replacing the `{"ad": "what", "children": []}` part with a namedtuple instead of a dict

Comment: Did my code give you the results that you hoped for in a timely manner? I'm curious about the results from passing hundreds of bookmark objects to it.

Comment: I haven't passed yet the actual data as I am still reading/testing the code.
From what I have seen it should be fine and fast. Especially by checking the edits from the starting code to the final one it helped me to understand the logic behind.
My main question is, experience solved the problem for you and knowing all the ins and outs of the python basic methods or something else?

Comment: I see, so it's quite evident that I wouldn't have arrived in this solution with my current knowledge. In my case I was stuck with the solution of the folder/file path kind of making the secondary dictionary and then recreating the merged one.

Comment: Telling me that you are searching through the edit history to understand, compelled me to edit my answer with a full explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to merge these easily, one realization needs to be had ~ every `dict` in the entire structure is a `dict` that may have a `children` key. Since that key is a "maybe" we can derive that at the very least, every `dict` is just a `dict`, and we should treat them identically.

A very good way to do this is through the use of recursion. We can input the entire structure and have it feed child dictionaries back into itself so, everything goes through the exact same process.

The code works as such:

The current `data` dict to be merged is passed simultaneously with the `targ` dict to be merged to. If the `targ` dict is empty, it is immediately updated with the `data` dict contents. Then all of the `children` of the `data` dict are iterated. On each iteration a check is made to find a child on `targ` with a matching `guid`. Matches are returned as the index of the match within the `children` list. If no match is found the index is defaulted to `-1`. This is because, if no match is found we are going to append an empty dict to the end of the list. Finally the current child of `data['children']` and the dict at the index of `targ['children']` are passed back into the function and the process starts over.

It's just a bunch of "do my children guids match your children guids?" and if not, make as many new dictionaries as necessary to accommodate the new children. If there is a matching child send the matches through to see if their children match. On and on until there is no more data.

Triggering the `update` line is the equivalent of saying. "I didn't have this child but, now I do.", with the only exception being the very first call of `r_merge`. In that case it's like saying "I didn't have anything, and now I am identical to all of this first bookmark object". That also means that after the very first `update` nothing really happens until you get to the 2nd bookmark object. It just runs through children lists that perfectly match.

###### SOLUTION

```py
#merge data to targ by eid recursing on r_key
def r_merge(data:dict, targ:dict, eid:str, r_key:str) -> None:
    #guard clause
    if not data.get(eid): raise ValueError
    
    #update if empty
    if not targ: targ.update(data)
        
    #process children
    for entry in data.get(r_key, []):
        #find match index else default to -1
        i = next((i for i, ent in enumerate(targ[r_key]) if ent[eid] == entry[eid]), -1)
        
        #no match, prime with empty dict
        if i<0: targ[r_key].append(dict())
        
        #recursive merge
        r_merge(entry, targ[r_key][i], eid, r_key)
```

###### USAGE

```py
import json

json1={'guid': 'root________', 'title': '', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1697130233008000, 'id': 1, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'placesRoot', 'children': [{'guid': 'menu________', 'title': 'menu', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1697130233008000, 'id': 2, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'bookmarksMenuFolder', 'children': [{'guid': '9GEAbdFPVBqv', 'title': 'Getting started - mypy 1.5.1 documentation', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1696274666207000, 'lastModified': 1696274666207000, 'id': 16, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html'}, {'guid': 'PDKXoMPpSKZ9', 'title': 'testFolder2', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130042452000, 'lastModified': 1697130183178000, 'id': 18, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'jbP4ff424REs', 'title': 'Secure Coding with Python', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130058445000, 'lastModified': 1697130058445000, 'id': 19, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://devopedia.org/secure-coding-with-python'}, {'guid': 'bZSAKQe67MEP', 'title': 'testSubFolder', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130074677000, 'lastModified': 1697130183178000, 'id': 20, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': '0U5O4Rw6M3M5', 'title': 'Typer', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130183178000, 'lastModified': 1697130183178000, 'id': 21, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://typer.tiangolo.com/'}]}]}, {'guid': '-j27AP1Cwt0O', 'title': 'testFolder1', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1697130021758000, 'lastModified': 1697130233008000, 'id': 17, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'Wb3-R2DDT8Ip', 'title': 'Welcome to Click — Click Documentation (8.1.x)', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130230240000, 'lastModified': 1697130230240000, 'id': 22, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/'}]}, {'guid': 'VDTmkniLNlvN', 'title': 'Mozilla Firefox', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1697129949344000, 'id': 7, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'vUwrKuzYfywC', 'title': 'Get Help', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 8, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox'}, {'guid': 'mKpEl6U5Pppr', 'title': 'Customize Firefox', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 9, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize'}, {'guid': 'Rw167-bbT1fR', 'title': 'Get Involved', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 10, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/contribute/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/contribute/'}, {'guid': 'stHPEtkREVvD', 'title': 'About Us', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 11, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/about/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/about/'}]}]}, {'guid': 'toolbar_____', 'title': 'toolbar', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1696274298931000, 'id': 3, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'toolbarFolder', 'children': [{'guid': '690YbVlf5eS_', 'title': 'Getting Started', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927107484000, 'lastModified': 1688927107484000, 'id': 12, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/'}, {'guid': 'YJ_gjoZ6Wwj1', 'title': 'json — JSON encoder and decoder — Python 3.11.5 documentation', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1696274298931000, 'lastModified': 1696274298931000, 'id': 13, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html'}]}, {'guid': 'unfiled_____', 'title': 'unfiled', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1688927107332000, 'id': 5, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'unfiledBookmarksFolder'}, {'guid': 'mobile______', 'title': 'mobile', 'index': 4, 'dateAdded': 1688927106942000, 'lastModified': 1688927107332000, 'id': 6, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'mobileFolder'}]}
json2={'guid': 'root________', 'title': '', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 1, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'placesRoot', 'children': [{'guid': 'menu________', 'title': 'menu', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 2, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'bookmarksMenuFolder', 'children': [{'guid': '9GEAbdFPVBqv', 'title': 'Getting started - mypy 1.5.1 documentation', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1696274666207000, 'lastModified': 1696274666207000, 'id': 16, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html'}, {'guid': 'FNxknWay_xr8', 'title': "Command-line Applications — The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python", 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130502023000, 'lastModified': 1697130502023000, 'id': 23, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/cli/'}, {'guid': 'PDKXoMPpSKZ9', 'title': 'testFolder2', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1697130042452000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 18, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'bZSAKQe67MEP', 'title': 'testSubFolder', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130074677000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 20, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'm6MBObvLXgt6', 'title': 'The Python Fire Guide - Python Fire', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130663668000, 'lastModified': 1697130663668000, 'id': 28, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://google.github.io/python-fire/guide/'}, {'guid': 'fl2vHRLT-RJY', 'title': 'Typer', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697131416648000, 'lastModified': 1697131416648000, 'id': 30, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://typer.tiangolo.com/'}]}, {'guid': 'Z2khP-DX2nJU', 'title': 'testsubF2', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130537074000, 'lastModified': 1697130642695000, 'id': 26, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'ZHUGVs2ZYUiA', 'title': 'argparse — Parser for command-line options, arguments and sub-commands — Python 3.12.0 documentation', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130642695000, 'lastModified': 1697130642695000, 'id': 27, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html'}]}, {'guid': '3RP_KOI4Pq0q', 'title': 'plac · PyPI', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1697130513781000, 'lastModified': 1697130513781000, 'id': 24, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://pypi.org/project/plac/'}]}, {'guid': '-j27AP1Cwt0O', 'title': 'testFolder1', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1697130021758000, 'lastModified': 1697130520562000, 'id': 17, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'Wb3-R2DDT8Ip', 'title': 'Welcome to Click — Click Documentation (8.1.x)', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1697130230240000, 'lastModified': 1697130230240000, 'id': 22, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/'}, {'guid': 'zuT4_jp_Rj5l', 'title': 'cliff – Command Line Interface Formulation Framework — cliff 4.3.1.dev12 documentation', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1697130520562000, 'lastModified': 1697130520562000, 'id': 25, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.openstack.org/cliff/latest/'}]}, {'guid': 'LjrKYDavnU7w', 'title': 'Generating Command-Line Interfaces (CLI) with Fire in Python', 'index': 4, 'dateAdded': 1697130696550000, 'lastModified': 1697130696550000, 'id': 29, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://stackabuse.com/generating-command-line-interfaces-cli-with-fire-in-python/'}, {'guid': 'VDTmkniLNlvN', 'title': 'Mozilla Firefox', 'index': 5, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1697129949344000, 'id': 7, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'children': [{'guid': 'vUwrKuzYfywC', 'title': 'Get Help', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 8, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://support.mozilla.org/products/firefox'}, {'guid': 'mKpEl6U5Pppr', 'title': 'Customize Firefox', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 9, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customize-firefox-controls-buttons-and-toolbars?utm_source=firefox-browser&utm_medium=default-bookmarks&utm_campaign=customize'}, {'guid': 'Rw167-bbT1fR', 'title': 'Get Involved', 'index': 2, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 10, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/contribute/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/contribute/'}, {'guid': 'stHPEtkREVvD', 'title': 'About Us', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927107386000, 'lastModified': 1688927107386000, 'id': 11, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/about/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/about/'}]}]}, {'guid': 'toolbar_____', 'title': 'toolbar', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1696274298931000, 'id': 3, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'toolbarFolder', 'children': [{'guid': '690YbVlf5eS_', 'title': 'Getting Started', 'index': 0, 'dateAdded': 1688927107484000, 'lastModified': 1688927107484000, 'id': 12, 'typeCode': 1, 'iconUri': 'fake-favicon-uri:https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/', 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/central/'}, {'guid': 'YJ_gjoZ6Wwj1', 'title': 'json — JSON encoder and decoder — Python 3.11.5 documentation', 'index': 1, 'dateAdded': 1696274298931000, 'lastModified': 1696274298931000, 'id': 13, 'typeCode': 1, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place', 'uri': 'https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html'}]}, {'guid': 'unfiled_____', 'title': 'unfiled', 'index': 3, 'dateAdded': 1688927106926000, 'lastModified': 1688927107332000, 'id': 5, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'unfiledBookmarksFolder'}, {'guid': 'mobile______', 'title': 'mobile', 'index': 4, 'dateAdded': 1688927106942000, 'lastModified': 1688927107332000, 'id': 6, 'typeCode': 2, 'type': 'text/x-moz-place-container', 'root': 'mobileFolder'}]} 

results = dict()          #for storing results
datas   = (json1, json2)  #gather dicts for iteration

for data in datas:
    r_merge(data, results, 'guid', 'children') #recursive merge
    
#print results        
print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution, using `defaultdict`:

```py
dct = {
    "main_folder/": ["folder_main_folder", {"id": "main_folder", "ad": "what"}],
    "main_folder/subfolder1/": [
        "folder_subfolder1",
        {"id": "subfolder1", "ad": "what"},
    ],
    "main_folder/subfolder1/9GEAbdFPVBqv/": [
        "file_9GEAbdFPVBqv",
        {"id": "9GEAbdFPVBqv", "ad": "what1"},
    ],
    "main_folder/subfolder1/eaXY8H5Y1cJ_/": [
        "folder_eaXY8H5Y1cJ_",
        {"id": "eaXY8H5Y1cJ_", "ad": "what2"},
    ],
    "main_folder/subfolder1/eaXY8H5Y1cJ_/9p2UFp7-qcEt/": [
        "file_9p2UFp7-qcEt",
        {"id": "9p2UFp7-qcEt", "ad": "what3"},
    ],
    "main_folder/subfolder1/fijaCypbmbU1/": [
        "file_fijaCypbmbU1",
        {"id": "fijaCypbmbU1", "ad": "what4"},
    ],
    "main_folder/subfolder2/": [
        "folder_subfolder2",
        {"id": "subfolder2", "ad": "what7"},
    ],
}

from collections import defaultdict


def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)


out = tree()

for keys, (name, data) in zip((k.strip("/").split("/") for k in dct), dct.values()):
    head = out
    for k in keys:
        head = head[k]
    head.update(data)


def convert(dct):
    out = {}
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if k in {"id", "ad"}:
            out[k] = v
        else:
            out.setdefault("children", [])
            out["children"].append(convert(v))
    return out


out = convert(out)
print(out["children"][0])
```

Prints:

```
{
    "id": "main_folder",
    "ad": "what",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "subfolder1",
            "ad": "what",
            "children": [
                {"id": "9GEAbdFPVBqv", "ad": "what1"},
                {
                    "id": "eaXY8H5Y1cJ_",
                    "ad": "what2",
                    "children": [{"id": "9p2UFp7-qcEt", "ad": "what3"}],
                },
                {"id": "fijaCypbmbU1", "ad": "what4"},
            ],
        },
        {"id": "subfolder2", "ad": "what7"},
    ],
}
```

Comment: @KY It seems you've got string instead of dictionary. Did you forget parse the Json string using `json.load` ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, if you check my update you will see that actually there are not "id" "ad" keys in the actual json but is quite more complicated. I dont't know if that could play a role.